# Kendo UI dropdown not updating angular scope

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have 2 kendo UI drop downs. Change the first dropdown updates the items in the second dropdown - think state and county drop downs.

Here's a dojo showing the working behavior:
http://dojo.telerik.com/USuhi/2

The issue if if you follow these steps.

1. Select "IN" in 1st dropdown
2. Select "IN 7" in 2nd dropdown
3. Select "optionLabel" in 1st dropdown
4. Select "IN" in 1st dropdown
5. Select "IN 7" in 2nd dropdown

You'd expect selected.county to be {"id": 7,"text": "IN 7"}, bu it's actually null!

Is there a better way to get angular and kendo-ui to play nice together and get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the dojo, try changing this line

```
$scope.selected.county = null;
```

with

```
if ($scope.selected.state.text == "optionLabel") {
  $scope.selected.county = null;
} else {
  $scope.selected.county = {};
}
```

Of course you should do a more specific search for the empty item, maybe on an id (ex. -1).

Comment: Just curious. Do you think this behavior is expected? Or is it it a bug?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, I've tested a little more in the dojo and you current code works if you choose the second time another item from the second dropdown. My guess is either kendo ui has some sort of cache for the model or it is because you assign it to `null` and after you update the `counties` and some internal checks in the kendo ui when setting the value to the `ng-model` is not passing. It works if you put the `$scope.selected.county = null;` at the end of the function. If I have time tomorrow I'll check kendo ui code.